# how to set a parameter to a list in stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

The example and the thing I want to achieve is here

```
set.seed(13231)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20, 10, 1), y = rnorm(20, 0.2))


ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = df) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.0 * x^2) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.005 * x^2) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.01 * x^2) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.02 * x^2) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.03 * x^2)
```

The question is: is this possible to change the code that I will have just one line of `stat_function` with floating variable that is currently `c(0.0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03)`. Something like `stat_function(fun = function(x) c() * x^2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply`

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = df) +
  geom_point() +
  lapply(c(0.0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03), 
         function(i) stat_function(fun = function(x) i * x^2))
```

[image]

From `help("+.gg")`

> **usage :** e1 %+% e2
>
> e1 : An object of class ggplot() or a theme().
>
> e2 : A plot component, as described below.
>
> **What can you add?**
>
> ...
>
> You can also supply a list, in which case each element of the list will be added in turn.